# vitali covering lemma proof question from royden

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Hello I am trying to understand the proof of The Vitali covering lemma. On pg110 it ends saying from (3), there is a natural number n for which the sum Σℓ(Ik) will be less than epsilon and I am not understanding why, but I do understand that for each term ℓ(Ik), it goes to zero, but why the sum Σℓ(Ik)? I apologize for bad notations. Thanks in advance.

[[image: pg109pg110][image: 110]

Comment: Remember that the tail of a convergent series in $\mathbb{R}$ must go to $0$. The sum you are referring to is a tail.

Comment: crazy i didn't realize this, much appreciated!

Comment: I would like to add that(for myself and anyone interested in this) bc the sum is bounded by the length of E, hence it has a sup, hence the sum converges to say S, then the sum of tails will converge to 0. And from hindsight we know that sup is the length of E.